# How to add a an option to tile background image

Tags: media

Is there a module or modules in Drupal 7.x that can provide members and or admin to have an option to "tile" a background image similar to what you would see on a windows desktop As well as having a color wheel option (to pop up or static on a settings page to change or add different color themes for the member profile page??? Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: Which background image?  The one for the site?  For the header?  For user profiles?

Comment: Currently it would be for the site (admin) as well as members. Currently site members have the ability to upload background images for their content; blogs, events, and profiles. But the images are automatically centered so the image is blocked